# is there any way to print a javascript result into the div where the javascript function is being called?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if is possible to do this.

I have my javascript function

```
function doSomething(){
   return "Hello World"; //its actually more complicated method but the logic is the same..
}
```

so, at my html I have this.

`<div class="someClass">
    <script type="text/javascript">
       doSomething();
    </script>
</div>`

So, basically, I want to is to print that hello world inside the div where is called.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: do you have to do it this way for an assignment or something?  this is not really the way you'd do this in the real world.

Comment: quick/dirty hack: `document.write()`.

Comment: Id prefer to use a .each but the information is being written by other script that I cant modify, which is the best way according you to make it @jdu ?

Comment: Here's a freaky example, that works because the current script tag is the last available element in the DOM when the script runs -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/8czwdq5j/1/

Comment: @jpganz18 If you're trying to modify the output of another script, you should just make sure that your code is executed after the other scripts code has finished. If the other script is polite they'll expose a callback that you can use to bootstrap your custom logic. Otherwise you can use a timer to look for signs that the other script has finished.

Comment: For the OP's reference... [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) :)

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK JavaScript cannot easily determine the location of its script declaration. As Marc B suggested in a comment--it works for printing to the document stream, but other applications won't work. Not to mention if you want the same behavior in multiple places, you've violated the "don't repeat yourself" (DRY) principle. You should instead inspect the dom document and find the element you wish to print "hello" in. This is easily accomplished with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.someClass').text('hello');
});
```

As laugri suggests, you should add an id to your div if you want only the one div changed.

```
<div id="someId".../>
...
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#someId').text('hello');
});
```

Comment: Just a side suggestion regarding the use of jQuery in this situation: you would probably want to use an ID rather than a class for this, to be sure to print your "Hello World" in the correct div.

Comment: Don't forget to include a jQuery-less version. My bet goes that [tag:jquery] is suggested when you add [tag:javascript].

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel OP has a jQuery tag on the question, so I think it's a fair assumption that he has access to use it

Comment: Try to edit the question, copy the content and then go to "Ask question" and paste the code there. You'll see [tag:javascript], [tag:jquery], [tag:css] and [tag:html] as suggested tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a unique div to find wherever you're code is executing

http://jsfiddle.net/190p77wu/

```
var doSomething = function (id) {
    var targ = document.getElementById(id).parentNode;
    targ.innerHTML = "This was inserted for id " + id;
}
```

and your html:

```
<div>
    You shouldn't see this text.
    <script>
        var uniqueId = "tmp_" + Math.round(Math.random() * 100000000);
        document.write('<div id="' + uniqueId + '"></div>');
        doSomething(uniqueId);
    </script>
</div>
```

**Edit:** or even cooler, if you have a properly cached JS file, you can do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/190p77wu/1/

```
var doSomething = function (script) {
    var targ = script.parentNode;
    targ.innerHTML = "This was inserted dynamically";
}
```

and this html:

```
<div>
    You shouldn't see this text.
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" onload="doSomething(this)"></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an `id` at `script` element , calling `script.parentElement` within `doSomething`

```html
<div class="someClass">
  <script type="text/javascript" id="someClass">
    function doSomething() {
      var elem = document.getElementById("someClass");
      elem.parentElement.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode("Hello World")
      )
    }
    doSomething();
  </script>
</div>
```